# using that vs. those in a grammar test

Tags: grammar

Q: I think both are possible options. Am I right?

- The author's point is that inner-city seniors should have health care better ***than ----- available to them now.***

(1) that ******

(2) those ******

Comment: How can both be correct? What do think "that/those" refers to? It is singular or plural?

Comment: It is not clear, so both could be correct, I guess.

Comment: Whatever it refers to must be either singular or plural, not both, so both cannot be correct. What's the closest noun to that word? That's usually what pronouns refer to.

Comment: What does it refer to? Is it clear according to the sentence?

Comment: It refers to **health care**, which is uncountable and so grammatically singular.

Comment: There is not one plural in the entire sentence. That should be your clue to which is right.

Answer (score 1):

It's "that", not "those". "Those" is for plural references. "Health care" is singular (though a very broad topic).

That thing / Those things

Compare:

*They should have better insurance than that available to them now.*

*They should have better doctors than those available to them now.*